# Error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependências

Tenho um projeto no Android Studio para uma solução na empresa onde estou a trabalhar. O projeto já tem dois anos mais ou menos, e quando o importei do **svn** para o IDE comecei a ter problemas com as versões das APIs, dependências... Alterei as versões como achei que estariam corretas (não costumo trabalhar com Android), mas na hora de fazer o build do projeto são gerados uns ficheiros, e num desses ficheiros está dando o erro do título. Em baixo deixo algumas imagens do projeto e os scripts no Gradle:

## Projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Scripts Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.veedmee.android"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 23
    versionName "1.194"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile project(':facebookSDK')
compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
compile files('libs/fmmr.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.1.jar')
//compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar')
//compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.1.jar')
/*compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'*/
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile project(path: ':notifications', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.8.9'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
 }
```

Quais são os erros mais comuns para este tipo de situação em que temos de lidar com projetos antigos e atualiza-los? Obrigado

Trecho do Registration.java onde ocorre o erro:

```
 public static final class Builder extends com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient.Builder {


public Builder(com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport transport, com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory jsonFactory,
    com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer) {
  super(
      transport,
      jsonFactory,
      DEFAULT_ROOT_URL,
      DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH,
      httpRequestInitializer,
      false);
  setBatchPath(DEFAULT_BATCH_PATH);
}

/** Builds a new instance of {@link Registration}. */
@Override
public Registration build() {
  return new Registration(this);
}

@Override
public Builder setRootUrl(String rootUrl) {
  return (Builder) super.setRootUrl(rootUrl);
}

@Override
public Builder setServicePath(String servicePath) {
  return (Builder) super.setServicePath(servicePath);
}

@Override
public Builder setBatchPath(String batchPath) {
  return (Builder) super.setBatchPath(batchPath);
}
```

Comment: Poderia colocar esta classe Registration.java para dar uma olhada nela?

Comment: Coloquei desde o início da classe até onde ocorre o erro, esse ficheiro é gerado automaticamente, não posso mudar o código..